# when plot throughput vs time, why 2 links with X delay each differs with 1 link with 2X delay?

Tags: tcp, throughput

First of all, I am fairly new to TCP, sorry if I miss anything obvious.
Also, any suggestion to help me investigate are welcome.

from my understanding, if I have a setup:

```
SENDER------SWITCH------RECEIVER
        A           B
```

if both link A & B have 0% loss rate & 100Mbps bandwidth but:

**scenario 1) A has 1~301ms delay and B has 1ms**
[image: scenario 1) A has 1~301ms delay and B has 1ms]

**scenario 2) A has 1~151ms delay and B has 1~151ms**
[image: scenario 2) A has 1~151ms delay and B has 1~151ms]

since the total delay of the network should be the same in both scenarios, **shouldn't the graph of throughput against time on sender side looks exactly the same?**

take the 60ms line in both graphs for example. Although the total delay in scenario 2 is still 60ms in the network, it never encounters another congestion event between around second 1 and until it hits bandwidth cap, not like scenario 1 which had many.

the two major concern are:

- **why does the shape of low latency line during the early stage be different?**
- **why do some previously unable-to-reach-cap cases could now reach the cap?**

some background info that might/might not help:

- I used mininet(virtual network with ubuntu) for the test setup.
- linux, so TCP CUBIC for congestion avoidance algo.
- the iperf command used

`recvr.cmd('iperf -s -p', port, '> %s/iperf_server.txt' % args.dir, '&')
sender.sendCmd('iperf -c %s -p %s -t %d -i 1 -yc > %s/iperf_%s.txt' % (recvr.IP(), port, seconds, args.dir, 'h1'))`

- cwnd for link A 121ms delay, link B 1ms (scenario 1, 120ms line)
  [image]
- cwnd for link A 61ms delay, link B 61ms (scenario 2, 120ms line)
  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have found the reason, but I am not sure. Any feedback will be welcome.

**why does some previously unable-to-reach-cap cases could now reach the cap?**

The problem is the switch's buffer size.

- In scenario 1 (link A has 2X delay), the real bottleneck situation is
  2X delay with K buffer  size.
- In scenario 2 (link A&b both have X delay), the real bottleneck
  situation is X delay with K buffer size.

Since this are lossless links, once I crank the buffer size up every case seems to be able to reach network ceiling.